# Break string at comma, rather than hyphen

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm using Access VBA to populate an Excel spreadsheet with information from the database.

I have a column called "Dependent Project(s)" that get's populated with project numbers. It's a fixed width column with wrapping text enabled.

Right now, the output is in the format of

```
01-04,01-05,01-
06,01-07
```

I'd like the output to be in this format

```
01-04,01-05,
01-06,01-07
```

My idea is for my VBA code to check to see if the contents of a column is going to wrap onto a second line, and if so, break the line at the last "," it can find.

Am I approaching this wrong? If so, what are my other options?

I have nothing more than a simple `WrapText = True` command, because I'm not sure where I need to begin with this. I'm not as experienced in VBA as I wish to soon be.

Thanks for any help you can give.

**Current code:**

```
'format Dependent Project(s) column as text, and wrap column
Columns("D").Select
Selection.NumberFormat = "@"
Selection.WrapText = True
```

**EDIT:**

I ended up using Brad's solution below; his solution is marked as best answer.

I did, however, need to alter the code a bit for it to work in my specific situation. Dimming the variable as a Range was giving me an error, so this is the code I ended up using.

```
Dim ProjList As String
ProjList = QF_CustomFormatFunct(ProjectKey) 'A function that given raw data
                                            'to builds a string in format 
                                            '"01-01, 01-02, etc"
ProjList = Replace(ProjList, "-", ChrW(8209))
```

After ProjList has the new non-breaking hyphens, it's populated into a Column D, which has been formatted to wrap text up above.

Comment: Can you include a space after each comma like this? `01-04, 01-05, 01-06, 01-07`  And if that is acceptable, does Excel then wrap the cell values as you wish?

Comment: I was able to add a comma, but now I'm receiving a few errors I need to debug. I'll update you and let you know if this solution worked as soon as I know.

Comment: Sadly, it still doesn't wrap the column the way I want it to. Now it's just cutting the line up one character over.

Comment: create your string with vbnewline or vbCrlf after every two pair to force the word-wrap?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with the string you have written is that both commas and hyphens are preferential places to break a string. If you go with the `01‑04, 01‑05, 01‑06, 01‑07` format HansUp suggests then use a [non-breaking hyphen](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2011/index.htm), `‑`, it should display the way you want.

You can use this in VBA with `chrw(8209)` like

```
Dim c as Range
Set c = Selection
c.Value = replace(c.Value , "-",ChrW(8209))
```

Comment: This ended up working great for me. I did have to alter it a little for my specific situation, as I was receiving a 424 error. See the edit on my original question for the code I ended up implementing.

Comment: @jtchase08 I figured you were using Excel in which case `Range` shouldn't cause an error. But if you got it to work just using strings then super.